# Unable to post to express app using postman

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, postman

[image]

I have the following code in my node app:

```
// POST route
app.post('/bb', async (req, res) => {
    try {
        // Assuming you're receiving JSON data in the request body
        const newData = await req;
        // Process the new data here
        console.log('Received new data:', newData);
        res.status(200).json({ message: 'Data received successfully' });
    } catch (err) {
        res.status(500).json({ error: err.message });
    }
});

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Server started on port 3000'));
```

When I try to send it some json with Postman I get:

```
Cannot POST /bb%0A
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It seems like you're sending a carriage return at the end of the URL (see the little arrow?)

Answer (score 1):

I see the arrow in the last URL `http://localhost:3000/bb[arrow]` in the postman, so you may delete that arrow and try again.

Answer (score -1):

look here

```
const express = require('express');
const cors = require('cors');
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

 const port = 5500;

 app.use(cors()); // enable CORS

 app.use(express.json());
  app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


 app.post('/test', (req, res) =>{
  console.log(req.body);

  res.json('okey');
 }); 




app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port 
${port}!`));
```

Comment: this is  an example

Comment: Thank you - but I accidently added a carriage return

Comment: your well come :-)